# How do you handle navigation inside a main abstract template using angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have this routes definition:

```
        .state('main', {
            url: '/main',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'main.html',
            controller: 'main'
        })

        .state('main.board', {
            url: '/:boardId',
            views: {
                board: {
                    templateUrl: 'board.html',
                    controller: 'board'
                },
                menu: {
                    templateUrl: 'menu.html',
                    controller: 'menu'
                }
            }
        })
```

The idea is that main.html is a frame that holds 2 views in which I insert the board and the menu template:

```
<ion-nav-view name="menu"></ion-nav-view>
<ion-nav-view name="board"></ion-nav-view>
```

What I want to replicate is something similar to a Trello board view, and with that definitions, it works. Now, I want also to add a inner navigation inside the menu, like Trello does:

[image]

But I have no idea how to define the states in order to achieve this.